# C: Why do elements of an array need to be scanf'd by memory address?

Tags: c, arrays, pointers, pass-by-reference, character-arrays

(C beginner alert)

I want to read in some integers from the user and store them in an array. So:

```
int main (void)
{

int i, num, cont = 0;
int arre[10];

for (int i=0;i<5;i++)
{
    scanf("%d", arre[i]);

etc.
```

When I run this, I get a Segmentation Fault 11 on OSX. If I run it with Valgrind, the problem occurs when I enter the first integer, and it tells me:

```
==1610== Command: ./ArraysAndPointers
==1610== 
2
==1610== Use of uninitialised value of size 8
==1610==    at 0x18F0BA: __svfscanf_l (in /usr/lib/system/libsystem_c.dylib)
==1610==    by 0x18718A: scanf (in /usr/lib/system/libsystem_c.dylib)
==1610==    by 0x100000F2D: main (ArraysAndPointers.c:11)
==1610== 
==1610== Invalid write of size 4
==1610==    at 0x18F0BA: __svfscanf_l (in /usr/lib/system/libsystem_c.dylib)
==1610==    by 0x18718A: scanf (in /usr/lib/system/libsystem_c.dylib)
==1610==    by 0x100000F2D: main (ArraysAndPointers.c:11)
==1610==  Address 0x0 is not stack'd, malloc'd or (recently) free'd
```

If I add an **&** in front of arre[i], if fixes the problem. But I don't know why. I'm struggling with the fact that I am reading in an integer, but storing (apparently) its **memory address** in the array. Yet when I check its value as it appears in the resultant array, it's the int itself, and not the memory address. Why is this so?

Note: I am fundamentally struggling to grasp pointers/memory addresses and their relation to arrays, char* etc. (see [my other questions](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1389110/pyderman?tab=questions)) and despite haven undertaken several C training modules with different providers and watched various explanations online, I've yet to encounter someone who can definitively nail the concept for me. Particularly, I'm interested to know **when** and **why** pointers are needed. If anyone can suggest a good reference/video/tutorial/article for me, I would be very grateful.

Comment: To complicate matters, I have had one reputable source saying, "an array is just a pointer", and another saying, "keep in mind that an array is not a pointer" .....

Comment: A lot of people say "an array is just a pointer", and they're wrong.  This incorrect concept comes from the fact that most operations convert arrays to pointers in the background and then act on the pointer, so for most operations, arrays act exactly like pointers.

Comment: In section ***[6 of comp.land.C FAQ](http://www.c-faq.com/aryptr/index.html)*** difference between arrays and pointers is laid out.

Answer (score 5):

Let's replace `i` with 0 here for the sake of explanation.

```
scanf("%d", arre[0]);
```

This code goes to the array, looks up the first element, and finds that it's 17 (or whatever), so it passes 17 as the second argument to `scanf()`. But `scanf()` is expecting a pointer, so it gets horribly confused when it sees a 17 and ends up crashing your application.

```
scanf("%d", &arre[0]);
```

This code *calculates the location* of the first element in the array and passes that pointer to `scanf()`. `scanf()` happily writes a value to the memory addressed by that pointer.

Comment: OK now we're getting somewhere. So it would seem then that particularly with respect to functions, the man should be my first port of call rather than coding what my intuition tells with respect to pointers(namely, I don't need them unless told otherwise). Can you give me a non-function example of where there is no intuitive reason to use pointers, but they are needed?

Comment: @Pyderman: it's probably not helpful to think of them as rules of thumb. If you understand that a pointer is an address to a spot in memory, then you should be able to sort out what makes sense. Admittedly, pointers-to-array-elements are one more level of complexity. Imagine that instead, this was just `int myInt;` and then in scanf... `&myInt`. Does that help? It's nothing to do with function/not function. Scanf needs the *address* so it knows where to deposit the value that it scanned. (Because scanf, once called, would otherwise have no access to the variables in your `main`)

Answer (score 1):

`scanf()` with `%d` format specifier expects `int *` as its second parameter.

So going by the standards you need to provide the address of the variable in which you are going to store the scanned value.

Man Says:

> d
>
> Matches an optionally signed decimal integer; the next pointer must be
>   a pointer to int.

Answering your extended question on pointers:

Any good C book would explain in detail why pointers are needed. Simply putting it you need some memory to store your scanned value. In this case it is the array and you need to scan the value to array by providing the address where you need to store the value which is given by `&arr[i]`

Answer (score 1):

scanf() method wants 2 parameters:

1. format of expected inputs
2. location where to store the scanned values

C language can only **pass parameters to function by value**. You can not tell a function to store a value in a parameter and that the parameter will keep this value (technically, parameters are copied on `the stack` - a LIFO queue - and remove from the stack when the function ends).
So if you store a value in a parameter (an int for example), **the value will be lost at the end of the function**.

If you want to keep the value, as you can't pass in the variable itself, **you pass in the memory address** (that is &var) of the variable in main memory (`the heap`) and not the stack. It will be received by the function in a parameter of type (**int***), which means `what is designed by this memory address is an int variable`.

So with this address (passed on the stack), **you can modify what is in main memory** (the heap), and the value written at this address in the heap will be kept even after the end of the function, because emptying the stack will not empty the heap.

You store the value in a variable at address a (such as int *a : a is a pointer to an int) by writing: `*a = <my int>`.

And for information, C array variable is in fact a pointer to the first element of the array (the address of the first element): `arre is the same value as &arre[0]`

And `arre[n]` is `*(arre + n)`: what is stored at (the address of the array plus an offset of n elements size).

Answer (score 1):

C passes all function arguments by value, meaning the formal parameter in the function definition is a different object in memory from the actual parameter in the function call.  Look at the following example:

```
void swap( int a, int b ) { int tmp = a; a = b; b = tmp; }

void foo( void )
{
  int x = 1, y = 2;
  swap( x, y );
  printf( "x = %d, y = %d\n", x, y );
}
```

The formal parameter `a` in `swap` is a different object in memory than `x` in `foo`, so any change we make to `a` doesn't affect `x`; after the call to `swap`, the values of `x` and `y` remain unchanged.

In order for the `swap` function to change the values of `x` and `y`, we must pass *pointers* to those variables:

```
void swap( int *a, int *b ) { int tmp = *a; *a = *b; *b = tmp; }

void foo( void )
{
  int x = 1, y = 2;
  swap( &x, &y );
  printf( "x = %d, y = %d\n", x, y );
}
```

This time, instead of passing the *values* of `x` and `y` to `swap`, we pass the *addresses* of `x` and `y`.  The variables `a` and `b` are *pointers* to `x` and `y` respectively, so that writing to the *expression* `*a` is the same as writing to `x` (similarly, writing to the *expression* `*b` is the same as writing to `y`).

A shorthand way of describing it is

```
a == &x  --> *a == x
b == &y  --> *b == y
```

When you call `scanf` with the argument `arre[i]`, you're passing the *value* of that array element to the function.  Unfortunately, `scanf` wants the *address* of that element so that it can write a new value to it.  `scanf` tried to interpret the value you sent it as the address of an object in memory, hence the segfault.

This is why you need to use the `&` operator on the `arre[i]` expression when you pass it as an argument to `scanf`.

Note that you *don't* need to use the `&` operator if the argument is already a pointer type.  Be aware that when you read strings with the `%s` conversion specifier, you will usually be passing an array argument, like so:

```
char input[81];
scanf( "%s", input );
```

In this case, the `input` argument is implicitly converted from an expression of type "array of `char`" to an expression of type "pointer to `char`", and the value of the expression is the address of the first element in the array.  Under most circumstances, an array expression will "decay" to a pointer expression.  As a beginner, this *will* bite you several times.

Answer (score 1):

The statement
`scanf("%d", arre[i]);`
will bit-cast  arre[i] into an address. 
This address is not allocated, so it is a so-called "wild pointer". Accessing address that does not belong to you is undefined behavior. If it is a system-protected address, the system will kill the process and give a segmentation fault.

> I'm interested to know when and why pointers are needed.

C functions are always **called by value**, which means that the **parameters** in the calling function is just a **copy** of the **arguments** in the caller. Modifying the parameters will not affect the arguments. A common example is

```
void swap(int a, int b)
{
    int tmp = a;
    a = b;
    b = tmp;
}
int main(void)
{
     int x = 1, y = 10;
     swap(x, y);
     printf("x = %d, y = %d\n", x, y); // still origin value
     return 0;
}
```

One reason to use pointers is when you do need to modify the arguments. You can declare (or define)  your function like

```
void swap(int* a, int *b);
```

and call like

```
swap(&x, &y);
```

Another case to use pointers is when the parameter is a big struct, copy of which takes too much time and space. Then its pointer is used. Sometimes a `const` qualifier is used to protect it from being modified (but not guaranteed).

Compare the following `foo` and `goo`.

```
struct Big { char dummy[1024]};
void foo(struct Big b);
void goo(const struct Big* b);
```